# PHP Laravel 5.6 -The Stripe API key is not defined! error message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated it!
I am trying to issue a refund in PHP Laravel 5.6 with Stripe Sandbox Enabled.
I am using a table and within that table I have two text fields to define the Stripe test and live keys.

This is my services code within PHP Laravel:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Stripe, Mailgun, SparkPost and others. This file provides a sane
    | default location for this type of information, allowing packages
    | to have a conventional place to find your various credentials.
    |
    */

    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('SES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],

    'sparkpost' => [
        'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
    ],

    'stripe' => [
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'key' => config('settings.stripe_sandbox_enabled') ? config('settings.stripe_test_key_pk') : config('settings.stripe_live_key_pk'),
        'secret' => config('settings.stripe_sandbox_enabled') ? config('settings.stripe_test_key_sk') : config('stripe_live_key_sk'),        
    ],

];
```

Here is the line of code to issue the refund via Stripe in my blade file:

```
            //issue refund
            $invoice = $booking->invoice()->first();

            if($invoice['payment_method'] == __('app.credit_card'))
            {
                try {
                    //refund via stripe
                    if($booking->invoice->is_partial == 1){
                        if($booking->invoice->amount_left != 0){
                        //     print_r($booking->invoice->transaction_id);
                        // exit();
                            Stripe::refunds()->create($booking->invoice->transaction_id, $booking->invoice->first_payment, [
                                'reason' => 'requested_by_customer'
                            ]);
                        }
                        else{
                            $transaction_ids = explode(',', $booking->invoice->transaction_id);
                            Stripe::refunds()->create($transaction_ids[0], $booking->invoice->first_payment, [
                                    'reason' => 'requested_by_customer'
                                ]);
                            Stripe::refunds()->create($transaction_ids[1], $booking->invoice->second_payment, [
                                    'reason' => 'requested_by_customer'
                                ]);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        Stripe::refunds()->create($booking->invoice->transaction_id, $booking->invoice->amount , [
                            'reason' => 'requested_by_customer'
                        ]);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set the right Stripe key in each environment, and just read these configuration values in you configuration file:

```php
'stripe' => [
    'model' => App\User::class,
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),     
],
```

In your case, that would mean you have to set these environment values:

```
STRIPE_KEY=your-stripe-key
STRIPE_SECRET=your-stripe-secret
```

You don't need the stripe_sandbox_enabled variable anymore, when you use a sandbox (test) key, the sandbox environment will be used automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! I actually figured out the issue and posted my fix below. I hope this helps feature developers with similar issues :).

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I actually figured out the issue in "vendor/cartalyst/stripe/src/Config.php" I changed the following code:

```
    {
        $this->setVersion($version);

        $this->setApiKey($apiKey ?: getenv('STRIPE_API_KEY'));

        $this->setApiVersion($apiVersion ?: getenv('STRIPE_API_VERSION') ?: '2017-06-05');

        if (! $this->apiKey) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('The Stripe API key is not defined!');
        }
    }
```

To:

```
    {
        $this->setVersion($version);

        $this->setApiKey(config('settings.stripe_sandbox_enabled') ? config('settings.stripe_test_key_sk') : config('settings.stripe_live_key_sk'));
        $this->setApiVersion($apiVersion ?: getenv('STRIPE_API_VERSION') ?: '2017-06-05');

        if (! $this->apiKey) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('The Stripe API key is not defined!');
        }
    }
```

and is now working 100% I can now issue refunds based on the type of key used. Thank you all and I hope this helps someone experiencing similar issues.